# lxc use NAT to access the internet, in container, execute ping www.bing.com already work, but open www.bing.com in browser, prompt TIME OUT

Tags: nat, lxc

Description:

1) I have only one physical NIC wlan0 and I use lxc to create a container named u1

2) I create a bridge name lxcbr0 and applied a static ipv4 addr to it, it's 192.168.55.1, then I modify u1/config to assigned a static ip to it when u1 started, ifconfig, I can see the NIC is eth0, and has a IP 192.168.55.6 which I defined in u1/config

3) I connected ap, and wlan0's ip is 192.168.199.218(dhcp), the AP's addr is 192.168.199.1

4) I then open ip forward by executing `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

5) Finally I use `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE` add the rules of nat

After these, I enter bash of container by `lxc-attach -n u1`, execute `ping -c 3 192.168.199.1`, and open another bash shell execute `tcpdump -i wlan0 -v` `tcpdump -i lxcbr0 -v`, I can find the output packet from wlan0's socket has changed, and ping has success.

And I configured the dns server, and execute `ping -c 3 www.bing.com` in u1, it succeeded as well.

But when I open the browser in u1, input the www.bing.com, it has a prompt `net::ERR_TIMED_OUT`

I just know, ping use a ICMP protocol and differ from TCP, but I can't know how to configure it, does anyone know about it, pls give me some advise.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the reason:

## ip route

192.168.55.0/24 dev lxcbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.55.1
192.168.199.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.199.218  metric 325

## ip route list table wlan0

default via 192.168.199.1 dev wlan0  proto static
192.168.199.0/24 dev wlan0  proto static  scope link

## ip rule

0:      from all lookup local
10000:  from all fwmark 0xc0000/0xd0000 lookup legacy_system
10500:  from all oif dummy0 uidrange 0-0 lookup dummy0
10500:  from all oif wlan0 uidrange 0-0 lookup wlan0
13000:  from all fwmark 0x10063/0x1ffff lookup local_network
13000:  from all fwmark 0x10064/0x1ffff lookup wlan0
14000:  from all oif dummy0 lookup dummy0
14000:  from all oif wlan0 lookup wlan0
15000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup legacy_system
16000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup legacy_network
17000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup local_network
19000:  from all fwmark 0x64/0x1ffff lookup wlan0
23000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0xffff uidrange 0-0 lookup main
25000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0xffff lookup wlan0
32000:  from all unreachable

I changed ip rule of 23000, like:

## ip rule

0:      from all lookup local
10000:  from all fwmark 0xc0000/0xd0000 lookup legacy_system
10500:  from all oif dummy0 uidrange 0-0 lookup dummy0
10500:  from all oif wlan0 uidrange 0-0 lookup wlan0
13000:  from all fwmark 0x10063/0x1ffff lookup local_network
13000:  from all fwmark 0x10064/0x1ffff lookup wlan0
14000:  from all oif dummy0 lookup dummy0
14000:  from all oif wlan0 lookup wlan0
15000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup legacy_system
16000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup legacy_network
17000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0x10000 lookup local_network
19000:  from all fwmark 0x64/0x1ffff lookup wlan0
23000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0xffff lookup main
25000:  from all fwmark 0x0/0xffff lookup wlan0
32000:  from all unreachable

Then it worked, the reply packet can reach lxcbr0, and the browser can surf the internet, but I still have question about the ip rule's output format, eg fwmark 0x0/0xffff or fwmark 0x64/0x1ffff what's the meaning? how ip rule worked? Who decisive the packets transfer direction? and which NIC will process the packet? Does the packets flow from different NIC?